# How to create archives for my custom blog-posts?

Tags: php, mysql, html, archive

I am having my own CMS for my blog-posts. I am using a database which consists of five columns named, 1: id(primary key), title, body, date, author.
What I want to do is to create ARCHIVES for my blog, tell me how to create it using php and mysql?

I am concerned to create a archive like it is used to be on wordpress website pages, I mean i can summaries the posts by date, month and year, which will count the number of posts on particular date. When any user clicks on that date by going in the Archives section, he must be shown all the posts made on that day.

Comment: You can archive your blog by constantly creating backups of your database. Or about what type of archive are you concerned?

Comment: That's not 5 tables.  It's one table with 5 columns.

Comment: I am concerned to create a archive like it is used to be on wordpress website pages, I mean i can summaries the posts by date, month and year, which will count the number of posts on particular date. When any user clicks on that date by going in the Archives section, he must be shown all the posts made on that day.

Comment: @DON ROBY: Sorry, I mistakenly typed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The archives you're asking for are just queries to your database to find posts in a specific date range. For example all posts of a specific day, week, month or year. E.g.:

```
SELECT post.fields FROM post WHERE post.date fullfills date expression
```

In SQL to find out if a specific date

- is a specific date, compare it literally against it
- is within a month, compare it's [`MONTH(date)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) value
- is within a year, compare it's [`YEAR(date)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) value

There is much more you can compare date/time values in SQL, this should give you enough to play around with it on your own.

Comment: But the problem is that how must I echo it on the page, Should I make a function like getArchives() and then call it on their particular page on which I would like it to echo?

Comment: You can echo the result like you echo any other result from the database. I think you already do this for the default order of your posts.